# .innerHTML vs. createElement() | setAttribute() vs. Direct*

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I was told this was not "proper", I did not worry about it until I started getting a run-time error in IE9.  Here is the code I need converted to use object properties.
Why is innerHTML not considered best practice?

```
  var c=document.createElement('div');
  c.innerHTML= '<a name="a1" class="b" href="' + d[2].value + '">' + d[1].value + '</a>';
```

Comment: never EVER put an A inside an A ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's strange that you're putting an `A` element inside an `A` element but the below should work.

```
var c=document.createElement('a');
c.name = "a1";
c.className = "b";
c.href = d[2].value;
c.appendChild(document.createTextNode(d[1].value));
```

This assumes that `d[1].value` is not known to be well formed HTML from a trusted source so it is likely to be more robust against XSS than the `innerHTML` code.

Comment: "I reject your reality and substitute my own."

Comment: I heard you like HTML, so I anchored your anchor so you can link to your links.

Comment: @MikeSamuel LMAO! too funny!

Answer (score 5):

innerHTML is perfectly fine, you are just not using it correctly.

innerHTML targets the content of a tag. meaning what's **between** `<a>` and `</a>`

you need to set your  `d[2].value` with setAttribute and ***only***  `d[1].value` with innerHTML

this should be fine (untested)

```
  var c=document.createElement('a');
  c.setAttribute("href",d[2].value);
  c.setAttribute("name","a1");
  c.setAttribute("class","b");
  c.innerHTML = d[1].value;
```

check these references and examples for [setAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/met_element_setattribute.asp) (method) and [innerHTML](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) (property)

Comment: There is no need for setAttribute with standard HTML attributes, just set the DOM property. It's more reliable and faster.

Comment: thanks for that information! i was not sure about that when it comes to not standard html properties.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are creating an anchor - by using document.createElement('a') - and then creating another anchor within it. So, basically your HTML is going to look like this:

```
<a>
    <a href="www.google.com">Click Here</a>
</a>
```

This is not right. This is the reason why using innerHTML for anchors is not good. I think you should do it as follows:

```
c.setAttribute('class', 'signature'); 
c.setAttribute('href', 'xyz');
```

and so on.

You can also set the href and other attributes directly on the anchor using javascript. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_anchor.asp (Anchor object properties).